# Pagination: how to know where a comment of page belongs

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm developing a blog system with php and mysql with the following db structure:

```
Article
   -id
   -firstMessage
   -lastMessage
   -body

Comment
   - id
   - article_id
   - publiched_date
   - body
```

The idea here is make use of pagination, where the article with a lot of comments shows a link tree like `[first][1][2][3][last]`, **10** ***comments*** by page. Everything goes fine, I have create a nice sql that select 10 messages according to the page number by url:

> example.com/?article=3&page=2

**Where is the ploblem?** Well, supponse that I have this url in my homepage:

> example.com/?article=3&message=3565

According to the url above, How can I determinate the page number where this message is? Do you have any idea to guide me to the right direction?

### Edit

- The messages ids are not consecutives, for example, an article could have the comments:  125, 364, 561, 1522

Comment: I'll throw your question back at you: *Where is the ploblem?*

Comment: sorry for typos. Post updated

Comment: Is there only one possible sort order for the messages?

Comment: @RedFilter, the messages are not sorted, because a user can make a comment to Article B, then Article A, finally Article C again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, select the comments from the same article, sorted by ID (or another column if the `id` can be *out of order*--non-consecutive is fine), and do a little math with the result. Here's the code ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/984c7/19)):

```sql
SELECT (
  SELECT CEILING((count(*) + 1) / 10)
  FROM `Comment`
  WHERE `id` < `comment`.`id`
  AND `article_id` = `comment`.`article_id`
) AS `page`
FROM `Comment`
WHERE `id` = ?
AND `article_id` = ?
```

Simply plug in the comment ID and article ID where the `?` are (or, even better, use this exact code in a prepared statement). If you change the number of comments per page, make sure you change the `10` in the query as well.

For this query, you just need an index on `article_id` (and a `PRIMARY` index on `id`).

Comment: Well, I have tested both queries, @Satevis and yours. Both work perfectly. Thank you guys for your time and help!  But I don't know which one select as accepted :(

Answer (score 3):

If you show 10 comments per page and request message 3565, you can do this:

```
$pageNumber = floor($_GET['message'] / 10) + 1;
```

**EDIT**

Thanks @Alix.

**EDIT #2**

After the edit made to the OP, without seeing what the database structure looks like, worst-case scenario, you'd have to fetch the whole list of comments as it would appear on the site and find the index of the message you're looking for.

I realize that's not necessarily what you wanted to hear, but there's no real other way to know without seeing what your database looks like.

Comment: `$_GET['message'] = 9` --> `$pageNumber = 0`.

Comment: But the comments are not sorted, because an article can have the message 25 and the 523 only, in consequence, this means that both messages are in the page 1

Comment: @AlixAxel, my db structure is in the post.. nothing more. I don't think that the db structure be the problem

Comment: `$_GET['message'] = 100` --> `$pageNumber = 11` *(don't worry, I made the same mistake)*

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to make a query, something like that should work :

```sql
SELECT CEIL((COUNT(id) + 1) / $nb_message_per_page) AS page_for_message
FROM comment
WHERE article_id = $article_id
AND published_date < (SELECT published_date FROM comment WHERE id = $message_id)
```

Depending of the sorting choose for displaying comments you have to change the `<` for a `>`, that query assume a `published_date DESC` sorting

PS: I don't know if it's a typo or not but you have write `publiched_date` in you DB schema

**EDIT**
If no sorting are made, rows are probably sort by PRIMARY KEY which will be like a `published_date DESC` sorting

**EDIT 2**
As @bfrohs says this query give inaccurate results (for one case but it will happen) if the test (`<`) is on `published_date` (or any other column containing non-unique data) instead of `id`.
As there are no ordering, using `id` is a better solution.

Comment: Wow! this have sence. Let me try

Comment: Yup, should be the way to go.

Comment: If more than one comment is posted in a second, this will not return accurate results. Additionally, the first comment on a page will have the previous page returned instead (e.g. for the 11th page, `10` *prior* comments divided by `10` is `1`).

Comment: @bfrohs Thx, miss the `+ 1` before submitting. Add informations about the inaccurate results problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the number of items to display per page and use that to divide the messages into pages

Answer (score 1):

It's rather non-trivial to go from a message-number back to a page. Easiest method is to simply pass the page number in to the message reading script, so you can simply embed that page number in your "back" link, eg...

messages.php:

```
<a href="readmessage.php?messageID=1234&page=7">1234</a>
```

readmessage.php:

```
<a href="messages.php?page={$_GET['page']}">Back</a>
```

this'll save you the trouble of having to calculate which page you came from, since you simply carry the page number along with you.

Comment: Same problem.. Where the `&page=7` come from? I had to calculate it previously

Comment: that'd come from your pagination system. there's plenty of Q&A on this site on how to build them.

Comment: Yes, when the user is "wrapped" at the pagination systems there is no problem because it works as you said. The problem is when the url exists outsite of pagination system.